# require_once(mage.php) returning error

Tags: magento-1.9

in my store folder i am calling cart_php to pull magento data in wordpress following is code.

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php');
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('default');
// This has to run to authenticate customer and checkout session calls.
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

// Get any customer model you desire.
$oSession = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' );
$oCustomer = $oSession->getCustomer();
$oCheckout = Mage::getSingleton( 'checkout/session' );
$oQuote = $oCheckout->getQuote();

//var_dump( $oCustomer );
//var_dump( $oSession );
//var_dump( $oQuote );
//var_dump( $oCheckout );
$html="";$i=0;
    $oCart = $oQuote->getAllItems();
    if( !empty( $oCart ) )
    {
        foreach ( $oCart as $oItem ) 
        {
            $sName  = $oItem->getProduct()->getName();
            //$fPrice = $oItem->getProduct()->getPrice();
             $fPrice= $oItem->getRowTotal();
             $html.="<div class=product-range-con>".
                    "<div class=product-range-image>".
                        "<img src=images/product-two.jpg width=40>".
                    "</div>".
                    "<div class=product-range-name>".$sName."<br></div>".
                    "<div class=product-range>".
                        "<div class=input-group>".
                            "<span class=input-group-btn>".
                                "<button type=button class='btn btn-default btn-number range-pdn' disabled=disabled data-type=minus data-field=quant[1]>".
                                    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span>".
                                "</button>".
                            "</span>".
                            "<input type=text name=quant[1] class='form-control input-number range-con' value=1 min=1 max=10>".
                            "<span class=input-group-btn>".
                                "<button type=button class='btn btn-default btn-number range-pdn' data-type=plus data-field=quant[1]>".
                                    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>".
                                "</button>".
                            "</span>".
                        "</div>".
                        "<div class=range-multiply>".
                "X".
                        "</div>".
                    "</div>".
                    "<div class=product-range-price>".Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol() .$fPrice.
                    "</div>".
                    "<div class=cf></div>".
                "</div>";
                $i++;

        }

            $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quoteData= $quote->getData();
$grandTotal=$quoteData['grand_total']; 
$shipping_cost= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount(); 
$html.= '~'.Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol() .Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
$html.= '~'.Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol() .$shipping_cost;
$html.= '~'.Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol() .$grandTotal;
$html.= '~'.$i;
}
    echo $html;
```

and its returning ajax error 500 internal server error. any help appreciated

Comment: Can you give me your magento root path and full path of this php file of wordpress so I can help you

Comment: yes http://komposter.os4wprojects.de/p/cart_pop.php this is the file , which i been calling throug ajax , base url is path which been calling this file in header.php

Comment: For include function try to add fill DIR path of mage.php file and let me know

Comment: its not working mate , indeed i just trace the code the error is in require_once file if i echo before this its returning , after this its throwing 500 error

Comment: Can you give video or screenshot of your error?

Comment: for error please check in the console  of home page :)

Comment: I got the Issue Just Writing answer Wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Now In your home Page has this JQuery Ajax Call Just Below

```
$('.addtocart').click(function(){
             var product= $(this).attr('mode');

                  alert(product);

                 $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            data: "mode=addtocart&product=" + product,
            url: "http://hello.com/handler",
            success: function (result)
            {


                result = result.trim();

                            alert(result);


            }

        });

        });
        });
```

The Above code has an extra )};

So replace it with Below Code

```
$('.addtocart').click(function(){
             var product= $(this).attr('mode');

                  alert(product);

                 $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            data: "mode=addtocart&product=" + product,
            url: "http://hello.com/handler",
            success: function (result)
            {


                result = result.trim();

                            alert(result);


            }

        }); });
```

Comment: The code is working like a charm, Thankyou so much for pointing out the error, You are the best. Keep Up :)

Comment: could you please check its not working again

Comment: Give Me both Url Again

Comment: have you been able to find error ?

Comment: You Need To debug code Line by line and check where the exact Error is

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala My server returns the error if I am using, require_once(__DIR__.'/app/Mage.php');  error : PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/abc/public_html/kolupadi_extension_order/app/Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/giritra/public_html/kolupadi_extension_order/sp_cost.php on line 3

Comment: @Gem Need code for that

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala This is my shipping estimation script which is located in public_html/kolupadi_extension_order/sp_cost.php  code : https://paste.ofcode.org/UsYq3KNpmit2NW3mhaZXbA

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala My error at line no.3

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala If i run above code in the location root_folder/sp_cost.php its working good, after that moved to my project folder like root_folder/kolupadi_extension_order/sp_cost.php return error at line 3.

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala finally solved using =>  require_once('./../app/Mage.php');